# Instamojo payment integration in react native

Tags: c#, react-native, asp.net-web-api2, payment, instamojo

We are using Asp.net Web API as a back end and react native for front end.
we provided redirect_url to Instamojo payment api which gets called automatically on response from instamojo (which may vary in time). 
How can the app get notified once the redirect_url gets called and show appropriate response message?

Comment: Did you find the solutions yet?